# Explode newline character not working, can only read the first line

Tags: php, forms, newline, txt

So I've made a login page and a register page. In the register page, you type an input, and then it stores the input in a .txt file that will be used in the login page.

Problem is, the login page can only read the first line from the .txt file. So if you made 2 accounts, you can only log in from the first one (the top). The second account onwards is unusable.

Here's the register function

```
    private function _regsave()
{
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $nisreg = $_POST['nisreg'];
        $namareg = $_POST['namereg'];
        $passwordreg = $_POST['passwordreg'];
        $text = $nisreg . "," . $namareg . "," . $passwordreg . "\n";
        $data = "#/config.txt";
        $dirname = dirname($data);

        if (!is_dir($dirname)) {
            mkdir($dirname, 0755, true);
        }

        $fp = fopen($data, 'a+');
        if (fwrite($fp, $text)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Congratulations! Your account has been created. You can now log in.</div>');
            redirect('Auth');
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the Login function :

```
private function _login()
{
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $data = file_get_contents("#/config.txt");
        $contents = explode("\n", $data);

        foreach ($contents as $values) {
            $login = explode(",", $values);
            $nis = $login[0];
            $name = $login[1];
            $password = $login[2];

            if ($nis == $_POST['nis']) {

                if ($password == $_POST['password']) {
                    $data = [
                        'nis' => $nis,
                        'name' => $name
                    ];
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect('User');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Wrong password!</div>');
                    redirect('Auth');
                }
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Account is not registered!</div>');
                redirect('Auth');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime I tried to log in using the second account, it always said that the account is not registered, even though the .txt file has all the data.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else statement (Account is not registered) is true because $nis is not equal to $_POST['nis'] for the first iteration of txt file.

Move else condition (Account is not registered) out of foreach loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$data = file_get_contents("#/config.txt");
$contents = explode("\n", $data);

foreach ($contents as $values) {
    $login = explode(",", $values);
    $nis = $login[0];
    $name = $login[1];
    $password = $login[2];

    if ($nis == $_POST['nis']) {

        if ($password == $_POST['password']) {
            $data = [
                'nis' => $nis,
                'name' => $name
            ];
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('User');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Wrong password!</div>');
            redirect('Auth');
        }
    }
}
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Account is not registered!</div>');
redirect('Auth');
```